# How to animate a span becoming visible?

Tags: html, css

Using the following css i have some cards, that when i hover over them will show additional information using an inside div. However when the div becomes bigger because the extra div within the existing div will be shown, only the color change is animated, however the resizing of the card beacause of the extra info in it does not animate. Does anybody now a solution?

```
/* geschiedeniskaart */
    .geschiedeniskaart
    {
        width:350px;
        background-color: #E0F0FF;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #888888;
        margin-top:20px;
        margin-left:5px;
        transition: all 1s ease;
    }

.geschiedeniskaartdatum
{
    width:350px;
    background-color: #001433;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #888888;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:5px;
}

.geschiedeniskaartdatum .tekst {
    font-size:1.1 em;
    margin-left:20px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.geschiedeniskaart .tekst{
    font-size:.9 em;
    margin-left:20px;
    color: #00004C;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.geschiedeniskaart .visibletekst {
    display:none;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.geschiedeniskaart:hover {
    background-color: white;
}

.geschiedeniskaart:hover .visibletekst {
    display: block;
    line-height : 30px;
}
```

The html looks something like this:

```
<div class="geschiedeniskaart">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<span class="tekst">Title</span>
</div></div>

<div class="row visibletekst">
<div class="col-xs-6"><span class="tekst">I am visble when hovering over tittle</span></div><div class="col-xs-6"><span class="tekst">Date</span></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Post your HTML too, better if you could create a **[demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net)**

Comment: @divy3993 Please suggest askers to use the built in snippet instead of using external resources, as they might make a question break if the resource gets deleted or missing.

Comment: @LGSon Sure will take into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Do it all the way like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var dd = $('dd');
  var dt = $('dt');
  dd.hide();
  $('dl').on('mouseenter','dt',function(){
   $(this).next().slideDown(400);
    $('h1').fadeIn(1000);
    dt.mouseleave(function(){
     $(this).next().slideUp(400);
      $('h1').fadeOut(1000);
      });
    /*can do the following as well:note the event delegationxx
    $('dl').on('mouseenter','dt',function(){
   $(this).next()
 .show(400).
 siblings('dd').
 hide();
   
      
    });*/
    
  });
 });

(function(){
  
 $('<h1></h1>',{
   text:"Hover for answers",
   class: 'myclass'
 }).prependTo('body');
})();
$('h1').click(function(){
  
  $(this).hide('slow', function() {
    $(this).insertAfter('p');
  });
  
});
```

```css
dl{padding:10px;text-align:center;background:silver;width:90%;margin:0 auto;border-radius:4px;}
dt{padding:5px;border:2px grey solid;font-size:2em;font-weight:bold;border-radius:5px;}
dd{font-size:1.5em;color:grey;}
h1 {font-size:1em;color:mediumpurple;}
.myclass{background:silver;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl>
  <dt>HOW are you bro</dt>
  <dd>very nice, thank you<p></p></dd>
  <dt>HOW are you bro</dt>
  <dd>very nice, thank you</dd>
  <dt>HOW are you bro</dt>
  <dd>very nice, thank you</dd>
  <dt>HOW are you bro</dt>
  <dd>very nice, thank you</dd>
  
</dl>
```

Comment: @ Michael,
I did, it's just a somewhat different approach, used dt elements instead of spans.

Comment: I edited it in, that's what I meant. Otherwise it would have been a link only answer which shouldn't be posted. Nice approach by the way!